# If no answers are offered in a bounty, automatic message should not be "you must award answer"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, bounty

I posted a bounty on [OSMDroid android app zoom in without changing tiles, is it possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192828/115) which, even after 1 week with bounty, received no answers (I have found a solution and will post it eventually).

IMO, the system should not send a message instructing me to award an answer if there is none (this is what happens nowadays).

I recommend that a filter for such solutions be created with an automated message to the effect of "Your bounty period has expired yet your question received no answers.  The bounty points you offered are not refundable.  You may offer a new bounty, if you wish."

---

Now posted at Meta Stack Exchange as [If no answers are offered in a bounty, automatic message should not be “you must award answer”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279786/if-no-answers-are-offered-in-a-bounty-automatic-message-should-not-be-you-must)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modification to [how bounties work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is not something that we at GIS SE can customize at a site level.

Consequently, you would need to post such a feature request at Meta Stack Exchange which deals with network-wide issues.

If you decide to post there be sure to look for any duplicates first because the site is quite unforgiving on anything tagged feature request if it has already been asked or is not asked very clearly.

The [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) tag that I am applying here is because we need to defer to the network of SE sites on this.

Comment: tks, posting on SE Meta.  should i delete this?

Comment: @tonygil I'd leave this here. It helps remind us of what we can change here and what needs posting at [meta.se] instead.